# PHP | ini_get does not reflect value given to ini_set

Tags: php, apache, ini

```php
<?php

ini_set('max_execution_time', 100);
ini_set('max_input_time', 100);

echo ini_get('max_execution_time') . "\n";
echo ini_get('max_input_time) . "\n";

// output
30
60
```

While attempting to debug a hanging php script I need to set `max_execution_time` and `max_input_time` but it seems that these functions have no effect.

Please note that PHP is NOT running in safe mode.

Answer (score 1):

Some hosting providers may disable it for "security" purposes.

The way it is done is disable the function [disable_functions] `init_set` on the PHP.ini file.

Check your php.ini to see if it is enable or disable or use `php_info();` to see all the configuration options.

Comment: `disable_functions` : `no value`, `no value`